# Is there any value to this patent?

Tags: expired-patent, us1808692

The inventor of [US 1,808,692 A](https://www.google.com/patents/US1808692) was my Grandfather. I recently discovered this patent online, so I am curious about it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the patent you are talking about:

https://patents.google.com/patent/US1808692A/en to Earl W. Sudduth

This patent is long expired and is now public domain, so it does not have any enforceable rights, unfortunately. (Also, there is no way to revive or extend the term of this patent).

Answer (score 1):

Although this patent was expired by 1950 and is entirely in the public domain, it still affects the modern patent landscape by serving as prior art for new applications, as these citations from recent patents suggest (see the "[Referenced By](https://www.google.com/patents/US1808692#forward-citations)" section in Google Patents):

```
Citing Patent     Filing date     Publication date    Applicant                   Title
US 5,474,016 A    May 31, 1994    Dec 12, 1995        William J. Haney            Overhead barrier warning system for trucks or buses
US 6,892,502 B1   Mar 27, 2003    May 17, 2005        David A. Hubbell            Space frame support structure employing weld-free, single-cast structural connectors for highway signs
US 7,314,020 B1   Dec  9, 2003    Jan  1, 2008        Bill Corker                 Over-height vehicle barriers
EP 1502999 A1     Jul  6, 2004    Feb  2, 2005        Siemens Aktiengesellschaft  Support for devices and signs for spanning roads
```